# Specific triangle, symmetral of angle proof

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In triangle $ABC$, angle $\gamma = 120$. Prove that $|\overline{CC'}|=\tfrac{ab}{a+b}$, where $\overline{CC'}$ is symmetral of angle $\gamma$ inside triangle. Look at image.

[image: Triangle]

I can't use areas, becuase we haven't learned them yet. Our teacher says that the trick is to extend $\overline{CC'}$ to have equilateral triangle. But I don't know where to go from that.

Comment: Your teacher on one hand gives a suggestion, but on the other hand, he/she has also added an distraction too -- i.e. "c".

Answer (score 0):

i will take your teachers suggestion and extend $CC^\prime$ up to $D$ so that the triangle $BCD$ is an equilateral triangle.

what can you conclude about the lines $BD$ and $AC?$

what about the triangles $ACC^\prime$ and $BDC^\prime?$

i will leave the rest for you to finish off.

Comment: Thanks. Now it seems easy, but I wasn't able to figure it out by myself

Comment: @user195929, you are welcome. glad to be of some help.